# how to connect to a remote Solr from NiFi: for example streaming of tweets to solr

Tags: twitter, streaming, hortonworks-data-platform, solrcloud, apache-nifi

I am trying to implement this example "https://github.com/abajwa-hw/ambari-nifi-service" with some differences: I have a Nifi instance in my local machine and a Solr version (LucidWorks) in my VM that contains Hortonworks Sandbox. when I try to connect to Solr server from NiFi, I unfortunately get this error:

```
PutSolrContentStream[id=f6327477-fb7d-4af0-ec32-afcdb184e545] Failed to send StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=03c2b3f5-43d8-47fa-ab6e-ad41e0e22f81,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1487148463852-14, container=default, section=14], offset=660541, length=6857],offset=0,name=103053148756602.json,size=6857] to Solr due to org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://172.17.0.2:8983/solr/tweets_shard1_replica1; routing to connection_failure: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://172.17.0.2:8983/solr/tweets_shard1_replica1
```

My hosts file in VM is the same as below:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost                           
::1     localhost ip6-localhost 
ip6-loopback       
fe00::0 ip6-localnet                               
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix                             
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes                                
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters                                    
172.17.0.2      sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

And when I try

`bin/solr status`

It gives me

```
    Found 1 Solr nodes:    
Solr process 11364 running on port 8983       
{                                          
  "solr_home":"/opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/solr/server/solr/",   
  "version":"5.2.1 1684708 - shalin - 2015-06-10 23:20:13",      
  "startTime":"2017-02-14T05:24:44.191Z",         
  "uptime":"0 days, 3 hours, 36 minutes, 37 seconds",     
  "memory":"101.6 MB (%20.7) of 490.7 MB",                    
  "cloud":{                           
    "ZooKeeper":"localhost:2181",          
    "liveNodes":"1",                
    "collections":"2"}}
```

and when I try

```
bin/solr healthcheck -c tweets -z localhost:2181
```

It gives

```
 {                                   
  "collection":"tweets",            
  "status":"healthy",              
  "numDocs":1,                     
  "numShards":1,                    
  "shards":[{                       
      "shard":"shard1",             
      "status":"healthy",           
      "replicas":[{                 
          "name":"core_node1",     
 "url":"http://172.17.0.2:8983/solr/tweets_shard1_replica1/", 
          "numDocs":1,              
          "status":"active",       
          "uptime":"0 days, 3 hours, 37 minutes, 5 seconds",   
          "memory":"27.4 MB (%5.6) of 490.7 MB", 
          "leader":true}]}]}
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks,
Shanghoosh

Answer (score 2):

The Solr processor's in NiFi use the standard SolrJ client, so in the case of Solr Cloud they are using the CloudSolrClient and being given the location of ZooKeeper which is used to learn about the nodes in the Solr cloud cluster.

In your case, ZooKeeper is at localhost:2181, so the CloudSolrClient connects to ZK and retrieves the info about the shards, which then says there is a shard at 172.17.0.2:8983.

What happens if you issued a curl command from your local machine to query that core?

```
curl "http://172.17.0.2:8983/solr/tweets_shard1_replica1/query?q=*:*"
```

If the curl command can't reach that shard then NiFi won't be able to either.

Possible reasons why it can't connect could be that port 8983 is not open through the sandbox, or that your local computer can't resolve 172.17.0.2.

The easiest solution would be to just run NiFi on the sandbox to avoid all connectivity problems, but you could also try changing the port forwarding configuration of the sandbox to open port 8983.